# Redirecting to the same sublayout in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Is it possible to redirect to the sublayout in sitecore? or I should redirect only to layouts.
I have a sublayout in which user can add comments and see comments. I want to redirect to the same page when user click add button - to display his comment. In the code-behind of the sublayout I've wrote:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InsertInfo();
            Response.Redirect("/Layouts/Sublayouts/Mysublayout");
        }
```

But it doesn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: One thing you should note is `Content Item is what makes your Urls`. `Sublayout` are `UserControl`s so redirecting to `UserControl` is wrong, not the way, and not possible. **Sublayout and Layout are just Presentation Component not the actual url**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the goal is to reload the current page, use:

```
Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ReloadPage();
```

If you need to persist any query strings that may be present, you can use:

```
var url = WebUtil.GetRawUrl();
Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.Redirect(url);
```